# Clear reactions edited embed message

Tags: node.js, discord.js, embed

I want to do is that when the embed message is changed, the reactions are reset, not deleted.
I mean that when someone reacts to the emoji and embed its changed, the reaction returns to 1 and does not stay at 2.
and when it returns to 1 I can send a third embed

[image]   [image]

ty

This is the code I am using:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Test1")
      .setFooter("Test1");
    message.channel.send(embed).then(sentEmbed => {
      sentEmbed.react("➡");
      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return (
          ["➡"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
          user.id === message.author.id
        );
      };

      sentEmbed
        .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"] })
        .then(collected => {
          const reaction = collected.first();

          if (reaction.emoji.name === "➡") {

            const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('test2')
            .setDescription('test2')
             sentEmbed.edit(embed2);
          }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all reactions by using `message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error('Failed to clear reactions: ', error));` and then add reactions back if you want. I would do this in a function so you don't have to add all the reactions over and over each time you want to update the embed.

Comment: can you do it for me pls?

Comment: What do you mean "do it for you"? If you want me to make the code and program everything, then I'm not going to, as this site is for learning how to code on your own. Go to https://discordjs.guide/ and follow the tutorials on there. If you just want a bot and not have to do the work yourself, go to https://top.gg/ and look for discord bots there.